# Ways to generate triangle wave function.

Tags: soft-question, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, approximation, periodic-functions

I recently when searching for parameters on a unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^9$ (we all have our more or less peculiar hobbies, don't we?) found a practical reason to implement a triangle wave function $t(x)$ which can be defined as:

$$t(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}-x, & \forall x \in [-1,0]\\\phantom{-}x, & \forall x \in [\,\,\,\,\,0,1] \\ t(x+2),& \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\end{array}\right.$$

What techniques do there exist which would give nice properties for approximations of this function? "Nice properties" include (but are not limited to) :

- good fit in some sense (for example $L^2$)
- smooth continous derivatives
- practical/easy to compute
- easy to implement
- fast to compute

---

**Own work** Having learned the use for fourier transform in my field my first reaction was to do a fast fourier transform (fft) to generate the function with the use of the fourier transform's basis functions (sines and cosines). The coefficients for these diminish quite fast ($\mathcal{O}(n^2)$) with number of coefficients for this particular function which is nice as we get then a compressed representation and also we get continuity of derivatives at the integer points which is a nice property in many cases.

[image]
Function to be approximated in blue and a smooth approximation of up to order 3 sines and cosines. Honestly it has been tweaked a bit to match the maxima and minima better - how to accomplish that automatically could maybe be a follow up question.

Comment: You have a periodic function, so your FFT is really a Fourier series - not an approximation of a transform of a function of finite support.  Thus you should be getting an excellent approximation without any aliasing, Gibbs phenomena, etc.  In fact, as you have an even function about the origin, why not just use a cosine series?

Comment: Yes great observation! I oftentimes do FFTs by instinct these days so I did not even think about that it actually has a fourier series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a Fourier series of your function as it's periodic with period 2. This gives a series of $$\dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{4}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos((2n-1)\pi t)}{(2n-1)^2}.$$

For instance, the first 5 terms of the series give an approximation

[image]

and the more terms you take, the better the approximation. E.g. 50 terms looks almost exactly the same:

[image]

Comment: Yes a series is enough. Actually don't need a transform. Nice one. +1

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to generate the triangle wave.
$$y = \arcsin (\cos x)$$

Here is a way to generate the sawtooth wave.
$$y = -\text{arccot} (\tan x)$$

Here is a way to generate the square wave.
$$y = \arctan (\sin x) + \text{arccot} (\sin x)$$